# Load Dynamic Library by Filename in D

Tags: runtime, d, dynamic-linking

Is there a way in D to load a dynamic library by specifying the exact file name and path? I want to implement a plugin system using dynamic libraries in a dedicated folder.

I am looking for something much like `Runtime.loadLibrary(in char[] name)` but instead of the name, it should take the full path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Runtime.loadLibrary` is implemented in terms of `dlopen` and `LoadLibrary`.

From dlopen's man page: "If  filename  contains  a slash ("/"), then it is interpreted as a  (relative  or  absolute)  pathname."

From LoadLibrary's MSDN page: "If the string specifies a full path, the function searches only that path for the module."

So all you have to do is pass a full path to loadLibrary and it should just work (assuming loadLibrary works at all, tbh i'm not sure it is implemented fully in the current release).